# how to extract a part of a string in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

I have a column called desc and it contains the below string  :

```
BUY 20 SAVE 5
```

Desired output: **20**

I tried:

```
SELECT
   desc,
   split (desc, 'Y\\s')[1] as Revenue
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Use `regexp_extract()` to extract the numbers, or use `substr()` to extract that if the position is same always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Hive `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function:

```
SELECT regexp_extract(desc, '.*? (\\d+) .*$', 1) AS Revenue
  FROM table1
```

See other examples in:

- "[Hive QL selecting numeric substring of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21142470/6309)"
- "[extracting a substring from a text column in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53217337/6309)"